# Adding migration to EF Core - error: "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've been following the following tutorial for Asp.Net Core:

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html

I've added the tools: (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre) and done as usual when adding migrations to any other Asp.Net MVC project, but when running the command: "add-migration test", I get the following error:

```
PM> add-migration test
add-migration : COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.
At line:1 char:1
+ add-migration test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Add-Migration], InvalidComObjectException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException,Add-Migration

PM>
```

I've tried reinstalling VS2015 and reinstalling the update3 and ASP.Net Core addon, but to no effect.

Comment: Did you solve this yet? if so how?

Comment: Sorry no, I've moved on to another project not using ASP.Net Core..

Comment: Thanks, managed to do it through the main system command prompt.
cd to project dir and run dotnet ef ...

Comment: Thanks @Krazibit312 for your hint!

Comment: Has anyone figured out a way to fix this so it can be run from the Package Manager? It's working fine for me, but another developer working with me is having this issue and I haven't figured out any way to fix it (though I did give him the workaround mentioned below).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I ran the cmdlet from the Package Manager Console inside Visual Studio. I tried to build models from an existing database, as described in https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html.
This is my solution (thanks to @Krazibit312):

- I opened the command prompt
- Navitgated to the project directory
- And ran:

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models

I guess you just have to adjust the arguments for your case and it should work.

For further information about the *dotnet ef* command see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet